# Hanging an antique clock on drywall (no studs available) using rope

Tags: mounting, drywall-anchor, rope-knots

I have an antique clock weighing 10.2 kg (22.5 lb) all told.  The only available space on which to hang it is drywall, and I can't find any studs whatsoever.  Also, the clock is made out of fragile old wood and only has one large mounting hole, originally intended to take some kind of hook.  I don't want to put anything metal in there because it'll chew up the wood.  I came up with a plan involving a pair of [rope loops](http://www.natman.com/type/rope-loops-rope-accessories):

[image]

The rope loops will be attached to the wall with molly bolts, each rated to hold significantly more than the total weight of the clock.  I'll then run some kind of rope harness through the loops and the mounting hole in the clock.  I have ten feet of nylon paracord (rated load 200 lb) to work with.

The *question* is, first, is this a sane plan, and second, what is the appropriate harness?  Which knots, where?  In what pattern should the lines run?

Note that the backplate of the clock is quite thick, 1.25", and should be as flush against the wall as possible.

Comment: How do you intend for the rope to secure to the clock backplate with only a single hole to work with? What will be the attachment method? Do you intend to affix some sort of hook to the clock, to hang over the rope? You can't just stick a rope in a hole, is there something inside the hole that the rope will hook over? Is the "backplate" removable?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it That's part of the question.  I was imagining that the middle of the rope would pass through the hole and be fixed to itself in a [cow hitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cow_hitch) or something like that.  I'm really not good at knots though.

Answer (score 1):

That plan sounds a whole lot more complicated and difficult than is necessary. Simply use a single drywall anchor that is rated for more than the weight of the clock with a long screw that will extend far enough into the hole on the clock to be secure. [These anchors](https://www.lowes.com/pd/E-Z-Ancor-25-Pack-2-5-in-x-0-625-in-Standard-Drywall-Anchor/3323542) are a perfect easy solution.

Comment: Please review the part of the problem description about not putting metal in contact with fragile old wood.

Comment: @zwol, I'd cut a 1" diameter circular plug of wood, fashion it into a hook (e.g. use two plugs offset) and screw that wooden hook into the wall using hafake's suggestion then hang the clock on it.